# CVE-2010-1807 vulnerablity (from android-json) in Spring Boot 1.5.3

Tags: security, spring-boot, owasp

When running OWASP dependency check I am getting following issue reported (vulnerable dependency)

```
CWE: CVE-2010-1807  
CWE-20 Improper Input Validation    
Severity (CVSS): High (9.3) 
Dependency: android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar
```

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3.
Doing `gradlew dependencies` I see that `android-json` is indeed dependency of Spring Boot

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor: -> 1.5.3.RELEASE
|    \--- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
```

How to check if this is false-positive or valid issue?

edit: this dependency is not used in runtime. it is used only in tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dependency is only used in tests, then it should be fine. Tests, almost by definition, don't use user input, and are not typically available to be run in a production environment. Therefore, a vulnerability in a test, or in a dependency of a test, isn't really a concern. I would reach out to the Spring Boot developers to ask why they have a potentially vulnerable library as a dependency, or look on their [GitHub issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a false positive.

As described in the [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-1807), the vulnerability is in Apple's WebKit that was used in Android before 2.2:

> WebKit in Apple Safari 4.x before 4.1.2 and 5.x before 5.0.2; Android before 2.2; and webkitgtk before 1.2.6; does not properly validate floating-point data, which allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service (application crash) via a crafted HTML document, related to non-standard NaN representation.

It would appear that the OWASP dependency check as incorrectly identified `android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar` as being part of Android. In reality the jar is a clean room implementation of `org.json:json` that has nothing to do with Android other than originally being developed by the Android team. It certainly doesn't contain WebKit.